# PDF file is not view in correct format in browser using PHP Header function

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers

I am using following code for view pdf file in browser but file is not showing correctly.

```
<?php
 $file = 'google.pdf';
 $filename = 'google.pdf';
 header('Content-type:application.pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename"' . $filename .'"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 echo @file_get_contents($file);

?>
```

Code output:

[image]

Please help! Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an invalid content type, you should be using `application/pdf`

```
// change this
header('Content-type:application.pdf');

// to this
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Comment: thanks but download popup is showing but it should show in PDF format.

Comment: @RaheelAslam that depends on your browser settings. More than likely after you confirm download, click on the download from within your browser, most modern browsers will show it in a new tab.

Comment: i do not need download the file only view the if any type because what ever browser version . Should not depend on browser version.Please guide me

Comment: Please provide proper solution for this so that i can view any type of file in browser if doc or pdf. it should not depend on browser verison

Comment: @RaheelAslam I just tested in firefox and chrome with this content type header, and it just opens in a new tab without downloading.

Comment: @RaheelAslam oh, that explains a lot! A video is worth a billion words. You see you have wrapped the whole document inside HTML? You need to remove all of that so only your PHP remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155950/discussion-between-raheel-aslam-and-jeff-puckett).